# Reading web-service information from assembly app.config file

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, configuration, assemblies

I have a plugin architecture solution written in .NET C# 3.5, where each plug-in is an assembly loaded by the main project.

Each plug-in can optionally consume web-service, so I would like to have the configuration of that plugin in its own plugin.dll.config file instead of having it in the 
app.config of the main project.

I have been looking around and I saw that i could load from each class its own config file:

```
// Get the application configuration file.
    System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap,userLevel)
```

I see how that would help me get the basic settings from the appSettings section, but I cant see a way to read the web-service information stored in the plugin.dll.config file.

Any help on how to approach this situation is very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [solution](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/10/19/loading-the-wcf-configuration-from-different-files-on-the-client-side.aspx) that overrides the ChanelFactory to use external configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've loaded in the configuration from another location, you can use a `ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(config)` call to retrieve the `<system.serviceModel>` group.  Take a look at the [`ServiceModelSectionGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.servicemodelsectiongroup_members.aspx)'s member documentation and pay special attention to properties like Client - I think it will get you the information you're looking for.

Good luck!  Let me know if you need more details; I'll need a bit of sample configuration that you're wanting to use, etc.